# C++, есть ли гарантии неявной оптимизации при сложении строк?

Tags: c++, оптимизация

Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
std::string a;
std::string b;
std::string c;
std::string d;

// ...

a = b + c + d;
```

Скажите, пожалуйста, есть ли гарантии, что компилятор сам догадается оптимизировать данное выражение?

Например, вот так:

```
a.reserve(b.size() + c.size() + d.size());
a += b;
a += c;
a += d;
```

Или такое лучше всегда делать руками, явно?

Comment: Уж **гарантий** точно нет - 100% гарантия :)...

Comment: Лично я не понял, о какой оптимизации идет речь? += не даёт временного объекта, а + даёт. Кто мешает сделать это (((a += b) += c) += d)? Если я не ошибся, то operator+=() возвращает string &.

Comment: Если заранее известен размер обьектов - то алгоритм будет работать более оптимально. Если мы не резервируем заранее - улучшаем быстродейстие (в поиске свободных кусков памяти). Если мы гарантировано значем что в reserve будет передано число не больше чем... там например 32, то `a.reserve(32)` будет для такого часного случая работать лучше (но жертвуем гибкостью, терям только время если будет превышен лимит).

Comment: Вот и получаем спорный момент, в зависимости от данных `reserve(const)` будет работать лучше чем `reserve(expression)`. В одних случаях первое будет лучше работать, в других - второе. И что считать оптимальным?